# increase size of MapboxGL.PointAnnotation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Using PointAnnotation, I see a small marker on the specified coordinates:

```
      <MapboxGL.PointAnnotation
        id={favouritePlaceId.toString()}
        title={customisedName}
        coordinate={coordinates}/>
```

But the marker is too small. Is there any way I could increase its size? The 'style' property doesn't work on PointAnnotation and gives overloading errors. What else can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of PointAnnotation, you can use a MarkerView. Inside the View, you can use any custom icons/images, text components etc and then  add a custom stylesheet to it to increase the size. Or if you're using font awesome icons then you can just directly pass the size={}

```
<MarkerView id={} coordinate={}>
<View>
<Icon></Icon>
<View>
```

Full example: https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/mark-a-coordinate-on-mapbox-map-in-react-native-5d21c71ed46e

Comment: When I use anything except the default marker the "onSelected" method for Pointannotation does not work on ios. Do you have another solution?